# Comedy movie about 3 software programmers who tried to hack the company's account system

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw a Hollywood movie around the year 2001, it is a comedy movie. I forget the movie name, help me to get the name.

I can recall few things from the movie:

- 3 men are involved in the main roles, 2 are Americans and another 1 is
  Asian or Indian.
- They are working as software programmers.
- The Antagonist character always wears Suspenders.
- The three people tried to hack the company's account system.
- They write the code to move little amount of money on every
  transaction.
- Surprisingly they get a huge amount in the account.
- After fire accident in office, all problems are solved.

Comment: +1 for describing Office Space without mentioning the red swingline stapler, flair, or referencing "sssss, yeah... if you could [statement], that'd be great".

Comment: @user2989297 and he didn't mention the destruction of the printer.  Impressive, in a way, that he seemed to have forgotten that classic beatdown.

Comment: Certainly not the movie you are asking about, but you may also be interested in [The Net](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113957/).

Comment: @user2989297 I dunno, sounds like Superman III to me...

Comment: Indians are Asians.........

Comment: @Levi: I'm not sure he is Indian, so I mentioned like that.

Comment: [Skeptics.SE question](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14925/has-a-programmer-ever-embezzled-money-by-shaving-fractions-of-a-cent-from-many-b) about alleged real-life "salami slicing" incidents. It even mentioned both movies as having drawn inspiration.

Comment: Oh, so THAT'S where that meme comes from!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[Office Space](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0151804/combined) from 1999.

> Three engineers have had enough of the daily grind working their dull, mundane jobs at Initech Corporation. Subjected to filling out useless forms, fighting with faulty office equipment, and their obnoxious boss Bill Lumbergh are enough to drive anyone crazy. There's also other odd characters like Tom Smykowski and Milton Waddams. When Initech announces that they're bringing in "consultants" to "clean house" (read: fire a bunch of programmers so that means a nice big bonus for the boss), Michael, Samir, and Peter scheme to reclaim their freedom with a software programming scheme that aims to take Initech for a small fortune through a virus that is designed to skim a little off the top. Unfortunately thanks to a typo, that virus skims a lot off. Realizing they don't have much time the three scramble to cover their tracks, but constantly shoot themselves in the foot. Can they recover and get out of their predicament safely? And will Milton reclaim his famous red stapler?

The antagonist wears suspenders and everything is solved in the end by a fire. Here's the trailer: